# imported distribution certificate not showing in keychain access

Tags: ios

So my client sent me the distribution certificate *(p12 file)* with the password. I installed it to my machine's Keychain Access the process seems to be successful because no errors was shown but when I checked the list of certificates in "My Certificates" I can't find the newly imported certificate.

I checked other list like *System and Local Items* but still I can't find the certificate I just imported.

This is the first time I encounter this issue, before every time I import a certificate it gives me an error message if it fails or show up in the list if successful.

Can anyway tell me what's is happening? I'm having a hard time explaining to the client what is wrong with the certificate he sent to me.

PS: I checked the client's AppStore Connect account and I notice a "Agreement Expired" warning, is this maybe the culprit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue. The client only exported the *private key*. Thus the p12 file he sent me only contains the private key and doesn't have the certificate (.cert). Because of this the certificate doesn't show up in the keychain access.

When I download the appropriate certificate in their developer.apple account and installed it to my machine then that's the time the certificate show up in the list.

thanks!